# Origins of distribute_setup.py file in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, setuptools, setup.py

What are the origins of the [`distribute_setup.py`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/distribute_setup.py) file in Matplotlib? Is the file originally from some other source or is it from the  Matplotlib project?

I am interested in using `setuptools` in my package's setup.py,and I want to know what the best approach to this is.

Answer (score 0):

*distribute* was a fork of *setuptools* with python 3.x support and number of bugfixes due to lack of maintenance of the latter package.

`ez_setup.py` is a python module that fetches and installs *setuptools* automatically on as-needed basis. `distribute_setup.py` provided the same functionality to install *distribute* package instead.

As of Jule 2013 most of the changes done in *distribute* fork has been merged back and packages should switch over to using *setuptools* again.

Latest version of `ez_setup.py` can be found in *setuptools* repository at https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/src/tip/ez_setup.py?at=default

The usage is documented in http://setuptools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/using.html